# Why should I use async/await vs Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

What are the pros and cons of using the async/await pattern vs promises in JavaScript?

Why would I use one and not the other?

Answer (score 4):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding, you cannot use one (`async`/`await`) without the other (promises). They are not alternatives.

The alternative is between using promises with `.then()` callbacks, and using promises with neater `await` syntax. The difference is entirely syntactical, not functional, so you need to weight readability (maintainability) against syntax support (possible tooling necessity).